# Title styling in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: html, css, ribbon

I have here an image to show my problem
[image]
I want to have a shadow thing below the ovelapping title. Is this possible in CSS of asp.net mvc3?
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23Fzd/) to demostrate it.
My **Hmtl**

```
<div class="postContainer">
        <div class="postTitle">Title</div>
        <p align="center">body</p>
    </div>
```

My **CSS**

```
.postTitle
{
    margin:5px auto auto -10px;
    text-align:left;
    width:280px;
    height:35px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Arial;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 30px;
    background-color:green;
    color:White;
    font-weight:400;
    position:relative;
}

.postContainer
{
    width:300px;
    margin: 0px 0px auto 0px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do this (not exactly a CSS expert). In the past this has been included as part of a background image.

Comment: hahaha.. actually I'm also thinking this is a little impossible but maybe someone has found a way who knows right?.. :D

Comment: @bot, I did not understand why you say me the answer???

Comment: I think you want to write Simon ????

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi I'm just pointing you to the answer below because you said you don't believe its possible :) ..

Comment: @bot, Are you sure. I did not say, simon said. Be carefull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these rules and it will work.

[image: End result]

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cC5C7/)

```
.postTitle:before {
    content:"";
    block:display;
    position:absolute;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background-color:#000;
    left:4px;
    bottom:-10px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(60deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(60deg);
    transform:rotate(60deg);
    z-index:-1;
}
.postContainer {
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

This is what is actually being drawn and we're setting the z-index negative to both the title and body go on top of the fold. This is why we need to set the background color to white.

[image: Explanation]

Comment: Practice, practice, practice :)

Comment: @bot I added the other browser prefixes fyi

Comment: @Tyriar I have a question. Is this approach also applicable to @foreach? so that each item in the table will have the same effect?

Comment: @bot pretty much, just wrap the `.postContainer` in a `@foreach` and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

That is called as `Ribbon`.

You can generate the ribbons using this site

[**http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/**](http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/)

It gives you the `generated code` which can be added to your element easily.